# how do i approach this error given in array and i want the error to populate on my Bootstrap alert

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

how do i approach this error given in array and i want the error to populate on my Bootstrap alert

**Ajax code**

```
 $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              
               if(data.status){
                SuccessMessage();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location.reload();
                }, 300);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
         
            console.log('Error:', data.responseJSON.errors);
                
            }
        });
    });
```

**json response**

```
{name: Array(1), email: Array(1), password: Array(1)}
email: ["The email field is required."]
name: ["The name field is required."]
password: ["The password field is required."]
```

**Bootstrap alert:**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it:

```js
 $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {

        if (data.status) {
            SuccessMessage();
            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 300);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        const errors = Object.values(data.responseJSON.errors)
        if (errors.length === 0) {
          return
        }

        errors.forEach(item => {
          $('.alert-danger').append(`<h1>${item}<h1>`)
        })

        $('.alert-danger').show();
    }
});
```

With specific columns:

```
error: function (data) {
        const errors = Object.keys(data.responseJSON.errors)
        
        if (errors.length === 0) {
            return
        }

        const errorKeys = Object.keys(errors)
        errorKeys.forEach(item => {
            const errorItems = errors[item];
            errorItems.forEach(error => {
                $(`.invalid-feedback-${item}`).append(`<h1>${error}<h1>`)
            })
        })

        // Please test it. I'm not sure the below function works
        $('[class^=invalid-feedback-]').show()
    }
```

Comment: by the way how do i use map for this? like display error to specific input fileds.

Comment: could you explain your output?

Comment: example.  error name field is required it will come out on the name field input below.invalid-feedback-name also if error is email it will come-out  in the email input field below invalid-feedback-email

Comment: the 3 error coming out in one input filed  $(`.invalid-feedback-${item.name}`).append(`<h1>${error}<h1>`)

Comment: i want to separate then take only the name as example

Comment: <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="">
   <div class="invalid-feedback-email"></div>

Comment: i log to the console this is the error ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: errorItems.forEach is not a function same

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Validation failed!</h4>
  <p id="alert"></p>
</div>
```

```js
error: function (data) {

$('#alert').text(data.responseJSON.errors.join(", "))
$('.alert').alert()
}
```